# VS Code using from flash drive with debugger

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

is there a way to use VS code on flash drive with the ability to debug and run some basics codes (using the console ) ?
I can use some different IDE but it must be able to operate from a flash drive.

Thank you in advance.

p.p Online IDE could work for me too.

I've tried VS code dev and portable versions but I can't get it to work with node.js and debug.
Also I've tried https://replit.com/ but I didn't find a way to run a code in that platform.

My level is junior!

Comment: "_I've tried VS code dev and portable versions but I can't get it to work with node.js and debug_" can you elaborate on what about JS debugging doesn't work with portable mode? Do you get any specific error messages?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here is that the system that you are using, needs to have a reference from the PATH variable to nodejs to use it. Even if it is present on the flash drive once you try `node ...` or `npm run ...` it searches in the directory of the PATH for a reference there and that variable is system based. What you can do is have some installation `.sh` file that easily installs it on your machine

Comment: Can you be more specific? I couldn't understand what I should do. Thank you.

Comment: are you using windows, linux or macos?

Comment: I am using Windows on all of mine machines.